# For each Loop, insert Color

Tags: vba, loops

One more similar question about insert color use for each Loop.

Question: the photo contains monthly sale amounts for 40 sales regions.write a sub that uses a for loop to color the interior of every other row(row 3,5,etc) gray. Color only the date area, column A TO M

```
           http://postimg.org/image/vhvj83wwd/
```

Now I select the whole currentregion and but I didn't know how to select **every other row** become grey

My code is below:

```
Sub color()
Dim rngcolor As Range, rngcolors As Range, shtcolor As Worksheet

Set shtcolor = Application.Workbooks("Sales Data").Worksheets("sheet1")

Set rngcolors = shtcolor.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
Set rngcolors = rngcolors.Offset(1, 1).Resize(, rngcolors.Columns.Count - 1)

rngcolors.Select

For Each rngcolor In rngcolors
    rngcolor.Font.Interior = vbgrey
Else

Next rngcolor

End Sub
```

Thank you very much! If you can help me , i have one more similar question [insert color , For each loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612649/insert-color-for-each-loop)
i hope you can help me either!!!!! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a For.Next loop with a step

```
For i = rngcolor.Cells(1).Row to rngcolor.Cells(rngcolor.Cells.Count).Row Step 2
```

or you can test the row number in a For.Each loop

```
If rngcolor.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then
```